# java: read large binary file

Tags: java, byte, binaries, large-data

I need to read out a given large file that contains 500000001 binaries. Afterwards I have to translate them into ASCII.

My Problem occurs while trying to store the binaries in a large array. I get the warning at the definition of the array ioBuf:

"The literal 16000000032 of type int is out of range."

I have no clue how to save these numbers to work with them! Has somebody an idea?

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] read(){
    try{
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.dat"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(bs);
        byte[] ioBuf = new byte[16000000032];       
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = in.read(ioBuf)) != -1){
            out.write(ioBuf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
          out.close();
          in.close();
          return bs.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: You can try reading it in chunks and then processing it. Another option is streaming through the file.

Comment: "500000001 binaries" isn't meaningful. What exactly do you mean? And why are you trying to read the whole thing into memory at once? What does it mean to "translate them into ASCII"?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer!
Reading up the first binaries I solved (see my answer below). Now I am trying to realize your idea (reading in chunks)!

Answer (score 3):

The maximum Index of an Array is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `16000000032` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2^31-1 = 2147483647

2147483647 < 16000000032
```

You could overcome this by checking if the Array is full and create another and continue reading.
But i'm not quite sure if your approach is the best way to perform this. byte[Integer_MAX_VALUE] is huge ;)
Maybe you can split the input file in smaller chunks process them.

EDIT: This is how you could read a single int of your file. You can resize the buffer's size to the amount of data you want to read. But you tried to read the whole file at once.

```
//Allocate buffer with 4byte = 32bit = Integer.SIZE
byte[] ioBuf = new byte[4];       
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(ioBuf)) != -1){
   //if bytesRead == 4 you read 1 int
   //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer!!

I probably calculated wrong. My data contains 500000001 numbers, binary stored as signed little endian 32 bit integers.

Comment: Then you have 500000001 times 4byte  ;) is the data formatted?

Comment: Hi! Actually I don't know. Isn't formatting a thing I should do when I use a storage medium for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to declare a large constant, append an 'L' to it which indicates to the compiler that is a `long` constant. However, as mentioned in another answer you can't declare arrays that large.
2. I suspect the purpose of the exercise is to learn how to use the [java.nio.Buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) family of classes.

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right! I really learn something about this buffer stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress by starting from scratch! But I still have a problem.

My idea is to read up the first 32 bytes, convert them to a int number. Then the next 32 bytes etc. Unfortunately I just get the first and don't know how to proceed.

I discovered following method for converting these numbers to int:

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b){
    final ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return bb.getInt();
}
```

so now I have:

```
    BufferedInputStream in=null;
    byte[] buf = new byte[32];
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("ndata.dat"));
        in.read(buf);
        System.out.println(byteArrayToInt(buf));
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error while reading ndata.dat file");
    }
```

Comment: 32bytes are more then one int? A int is 4byte

Comment: oh yes! You are right! That's why the outprint includes more than one number:
123456789

Comment: ok! I have read up to this. My file contains a lot of numbers, which are binary stored as little endian 32bit integers. So my first int number is 123456789, which consists of 32bit or respectively 8bytes.
:-)