# When reading and writing a file the output changes

Tags: java, file, file-writing, file-read

I'm trying read a file(doesn't matter the extension) and write after this, but when I do it, the output file is different from the input.

my code is the next:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
FileReader fr = new FileReader("rute\\inputfile.PNG");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;
while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
    content += line;
}

byte[] toBytes= content.getBytes();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(toBytes);
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("rute\\output.PNG"));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
inputStream.close();
```

If you ask me why convert into bytes and write from this form, is because I need do something with the data, and I need this conversion.
If you tell me that i cant load an image on a String, yes I can do something like that:

```
File fil = ~~~~;
FileInputStream fis = null;
fis = new FileInputStream(fil);
byte[] bytess = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
```

But I dont want do it by this way because if I want load big files, the heap size is not enough an this could be solved by the "line per line" read.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How I can read and write the file without changing it, or what the problem / reason why the output file is not the same as the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476280/reading-a-binary-file-into-a-string) before. Since you are reading binary data into a String you are changing the encoding of that data. So the output will be different.

Best approach is read binary files as byte arrays. But I will depend which type of transformation/edition/changes you need to do with them.

**UPDATE**

And, of course, you are editing your content before writing

```
while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
   content += line + "\n";
}
```

so the your output file will be different always.

**UPDATE 2**

Since the question/problem is how to read a big binary file, [google](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245) is usually your friend.
Or you can check this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529205/java-read-large-binary-file)

Comment: But if i read as byte array, i need to load the entire file in an array do not?
I'm doing the line per line because I can split the original file and dont overcharge the heap

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto What is a "line" in the context of a binary file?

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto Why should you need it to read ino a block? You always can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[]) or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int).

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto there is not "line" in a binary file. You read a bunch of data into a buffer, process it and spit it in your output. "Line" is usually a text file context. So, what kind of process you want to do?

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto Create a `byte[]` as a buffer (of e.g. some 1000 byte) then read from the file filling the buffer, process the chunk, write it, read the next chunk etc.

Comment: @glglgl
I do not understand your question. If I read it as a binary file, I have to read the entire file, no? for example, with my second method I read it as a binary file, but I need to read the entire file, and there is no differentiation of the lines, to repartitioning

Comment: @kszosze yes sorry, 
I do the " content += line + "\n";" edit to read it better, but in my output file i dont want change it

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto google is your friend -> http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245 here you can see some examples about how to read a binary file.. small files you can read it all, big files you read small pieces of, into a buffer

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto I didn't say anything about "google is our friend". The best way to partition binary files of an unknown structure is by blocks of a certain, constant size, e. g. of 65536 bytes. In my comment above I showed you the necessary methods for that.

Comment: @glglgl you are right, i see the wrong name, sorry.
and thanks for your answer, i'm going to try it

Comment: @kszosze Thanks, I appreciate your help and will review it to see if I solve it, but the "google is your friend" was not necessary, I'm not a child, and now look enough. even so, I apologize for forgetting that, I seem to have had any lacuna in my mind.

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto my neither rapaz. ;) se prefires o www.jujel.es seica tera-lo mesmo resultado. BTW, it's common make that mistake and be focused in one idea instead of look for the easy one.

Comment: @kszosze foi casualidade ou adiviñaches que son galego?

Comment: @AlejandroPicosPrieto, imos ver oh. Se fas click no teu perfil, vese craramente , Alejandro Picos Prieto
telecommunications engineering degree, University of vigo. ;)